# Reloading maven projects in IDEA: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I am reloading a maven project in IDEA when the error occurs.

The error description is:

Could not transfer artifact org.apache.parquet:parquet-common:pom:1.11.1-h0.gdd.maem.V100R023C00.r1-SNAPSHOT from/to mae-cloudsop-repo (https://cmc.centralrepo.rnd.konglb.com/artifactory/product_maven/): PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

I have imported the certificate as [the adopted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21076179/pkix-path-building-failed-and-unable-to-find-valid-certification-path-to-requ). And I try to install the maven project in command line by "mvn -U clean install". It builds success. But reloading maven projects in IDEA still throw the error.

My java version is 1.8 and maven version is 3.6.0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IDE launches the Maven goals with the JDK you choose in the Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven | Importing | **JDK for importer** settings. This error happens when the JVM tries to use non-trusted self-signed certificate.

It is likely that the proxy server in your network replaces the remote certificate with its own self-signed. So you need to [import your certificate into the JDK trust store](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/toolsign/rstep2.html) which you use to build by Maven (**JDK for importer** setting).

Comment: I imported the certificate into the JDK 1.8. But the JDK for importer setting in IDEA is 1.9. After I choose the 1.8 for importer setting. It fixes. Thanks. I have another question. When installing maven project by "mvn -U clean install" in command line, which setting.xml is used? The one in  user/.m2 or the one in maven/conf?

Comment: I changed the importer JDK from the default (which was under c:\program files) to JAVA_HOME. Now both maven command line and Intellij are using the same JDK (where I have installed the relevant certificate)